# Python: joblib does not work on custom-defined function

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I am trying to use parallel computation package joblib in python. I can execute the following example and get the result

```
Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(sqrt)(i) for i in range(10))
```

However, the following code does not work out.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
def f(x):
    return 1
def y(x):
    result=Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(x)(i) for i in range(10))
    return result
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print y(f)
```

when I run the above code, it keeps running forever without generating any result or message.

Can anyone figure out the reason for this strange behavior(I am using windows)? thanks

Comment: I can execute both of your statements successfully by placing them inside an `if __name__ == '__main__'` block

Comment: @lambo477, not for me, I have revised my post.

Comment: your code now runs perfectly in my Windows environment, Python `2.7.9`

Comment: @lambo477, this is so weird! Neither of my laptop and desktop can execute the custom-defined function `f`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line of code:

```
result=Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(x)(i) for i in range(10))
```

It should instead be:

```
result=Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(f)(i) for i in range(10))
```

You have to pass the function name to `delayed`, just like you did with the first example using the `sqrt`.

Comment: The problem is not in that line of code. That line of code is inside `def y(x):` so `x` is whatever you pass to function `y`. And in the code supplied above, in the last line, it is called using `y(f)`, so inside the `y` function, `x` ends up being `f` as expected. What you mention is not the cause of the malfunction.

Answer (score 1):

When I try your code it keeps running forever for me too.

I'm not really sure but I think the problem is in "delayed(x)"

If I try this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    def f(x):
        return 1
    def y(x):
        result=Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(sqrt)(i) for i in range(10))
        return result
    print(y(5))
```

it works as a charm.

It looks like your code gives an error but because the error is inside the parrellel part, somehow it won't surface.